# Words in context - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list and every time a word from this list appears in a text, I would like to replace the next two words

Ex.: list = ['Mrs.', 'Miss', 'Ms.', 'Lady', 'Mr.', 'Sir', 'Lord']

phrase = 'I'm sorry, but the lady is at home.'

resultat = 'I'm sorry, but the lady < next_words> home.'

I'm trying to do this in a dataframe

**I tried:**

```
def words_contexte(df):

    titres_list = ['Mrs.', 'Miss', 'Ms.', 'Lady', 'Mr.', 'Sir', 'Lord']

    data_frame_split = df['C'].str.split()
    words_index = df['C'].str.data_frame_split[data_frame_split.index(titres_list) + 2]
    df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace(words_index, '<next_words>')

    return df
```

**My dataframe:**

```
       A          B                                     C
  French      house                      Are you at home?
 English      house   I'm sorry, but the lady is at home.
  French  apartment          His name is Sir Ringo Starr.
  French      house      I'm Mrs. Carla and I have a dog.
 English  apartment                  Hi Miss how are you?
```

**Good output**

```
       A          B                                     C
  French      house                      Are you at home?
 English      house   I'm sorry, but the lady <next_words> home.
  French  apartment          His name is Sir <next_words>.
  French      house      I'm Mrs. <next_words> I have a dog.
 English  apartment                  Hi Miss <next_words> you?
```

Comment: What's the expected output for `'lady lady sorry lady'`?

Comment: @timgeb 'lady <next_words> lady'

Comment: Ok, so the second `'lady'` does nothing because you replace iteratively?

Comment: Exactly! The first one to appear is the most important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, avoiding looping over the each list:

```
list_ = ['Mrs.', 'Miss', 'Ms.', 'lady', 'Mr.', 'Sir', 'Lord']

def fun(x, y):
    in1d = np.in1d(x.split(' '), y)
    in1d_drop = np.roll(in1d, 2)
    in1d_replace = np.roll(in1d, 1)
    l = np.where(in1d_drop, '', x.split(' '))
    l = np.where(in1d_replace, '<next_words>', l)
    return ' '.join(l)
```

And simply apply `fun` to each row on the `C` column:

```
df ['C'] = df['C'].apply(fun, y=list_)

print(df)
      A          B                                            C
0   French      House                             Are you at home?
1  English      House  I'm sorry, but the lady <next_words>  home.
2   French  Apartment                His name is Sir <next_words> 
3   French      House          I'm Mrs. <next_words>  I have a dog
4  English  Apartment                   Hi Miss <next_words>  you?
```

Comment: Remember to let me know if this solved it for you by accepting @marin , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Connect `apply` to a functions would work, and split the value, and loop the enumerate of the split list, check if the title of the phrase is in `l`, if it is, assign the nest two items, then after that whole loop, `return`:

```
def f(x):
   l = ['Mrs.', 'Miss', 'Ms.', 'Lady', 'Mr.', 'Sir', 'Lord']
   l2=x.split()
   for i,v in enumerate(l2):
      if v.title() in l:
         l2[i:i+3]=l[l.index(v.title()):l.index(v.title())+3]
         break
   return ' '.join(l2)


df['C']=df['C'].apply(f)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         A          B                                      C
0   French      house                       Are you at home?
1  English      house  I'm sorry, but the Lady Mr. Sir home.
2   French  apartment                   His name is Sir Lord
3   French      house        I'm Mrs. Miss Ms. I have a dog.
4  English  apartment                  Hi Miss Ms. Lady you?
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a bit your function to apply it by row :

The idea is to get every row, split it and iterate through each word.
You check if it belongs to the sentence, get the index, replace the following word et replace the word at position + 2.

```
def replace_titre(row):
    data_frame_split = row.split()
    for titre in titres_list:
        if titre in data_frame_split:
            # Get the index of the word
            words_index = list(data_frame_split).index(titre)

            # Replace the +1 / following word
            data_frame_split[words_index + 1] = "<next_words>"

            # Delete the +2 word
            del data_frame_split[words_index + 2]
    return data_frame_split
```

You can then call :

```
df = df.apply(replace_titre)
```